# Remote interpreter deployment for python script

Tags: python, pycharm, ftp, libraries, remote-server

I'm planning to run a machine learning script consistently on one of my Google Cloud VMs.

When I configured the remote interpreter, unfortunately all the imported libraries where not recognized anymore (as they might not be installed in the virtual envoirement in the cloud). I tried to install the missing modules (for example yfinance) through the Pycharm terminal extension within my remote host connection over SSH and SFTP. So I basically chose the 188.283.xxx.xxx @username in the Pycharm terminal, and used pip3 install to install the missing modules. Unfortnately my server (due to limited ressources) collapses during the build process.
Is there a way to automatically install the needed libraries when connecting the script to the remote interpreter?
Shouldn't that be the standard procedure? And if not: does my approach make sense?

Thank you all in advance

Peter

Comment: could you guys explain why you dislike the question?
I apologize for beeing new to all of this and not knowing a lot of relevant stuff 
If you dislike my question you would be a great help if you also told me why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `importlib` to install your modules at runtime, but I'd just opt for creating a requirements file using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` which you can then use on the server to get all your dependencies in one go (`pip install -r requirements.txt`) before your first run.

If it fails for any reason (or when you've updated the requirements file) you can run it again and it will only install whatever wasn't installed before.

This way it's clear what modules (and which version of each module) you've installed. In my experience with machine learning using the right version or combination of versions can be important, so it makes sense to define those and not just always get the latest version. This especially helps when trying to run some older project.